Elastic search stuck after starting
I am trying to start an instance of elastic search but after executing it, it stops at one point and does not generate the enrollment token as shown in screenshot below.
Also to execute elastic search I have executed,
bin/elasticsearch

at the path of the elastic search folder.
Any kind of help is appreciated, thank you.


it looks like your are sending HTTP request to elasticsearch but it runs on HTTPS. Try like the following.
bin/elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token -s kibana --url "https://localhost:9200"
